# Transferring money on n Apple account from one iPhone to another

Tags: iphone

I have some money on my Apple account. If I buy a new iphone, can I still use this money to buy things on my new phone, or will I lose the money? Presumably it will still be the same log in details and account, so I assume that I will be able to use the money when I buy a new phone, or am I being overly optimistic? Thanks

Comment: Use the same appleid on your new phone and your money and prior purchases go with it.

Answer (score 1):

There was a comment below your question but I wanted to make sure it was clear. If you sign into your new iPhone with the same apple ID you will be able to use whatever money you have loaded into your account. You will also be able to access any previous purchases made with that same apple ID. Purchases including but not limited to, music, movies, tv shows and apps.